# Select statements in Apple Numbers '09

Tags: numbers

I've got a table as follows

```
| Name       | Year  | Price |
|____________|_______|_______|
| Foo        | 2013  | $10   |
| Bar        | 2009  | $3    |
| Baz        | 2010  | $100  |
```

What I'd really like to be able to do is a `select * from table where [Year] <= CurrentYear`

Since this is a spreadsheet and not a database, I'm wondering if there's any way to do this? Is there any way to do select statements in Numbers '09?

Comment: Good question to ask oneself: How would I do this in Excel?  Perhaps an INDEX(Match) type of query.  It appears that you want to return the entire record? (each field)

Answer (score 1):

No SQL or database connections plug into a Numbers file, so you would need to export it and get the data into a SQLite database on the filesystem or otherwise get it into something that has SQL query.